# How to write SQL like pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL procedure with this SQL:

```
select CenterExpensesID,sum(NISAmount) NISAmount
 from ktrn10_fnCostCentersTransactions(@month_start_date,@todate,'BEI')
 where AccountNumber like  @like_account 
 group by CenterExpensesID
```

@like_account is a parameter which can get a pattern e.g. '18%'

Is it possible to make a pattern which shows all the records "not like '18%'"

the pattern '[^1][^8]%' is not the solution because it excludes also 19,58 etc..

Comment: `where AccountNumber like @like_account and AccountNumber not like '18%'`?

Comment: I'd use [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to build a query that uses the `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE` operator given the value of `@like_account`

Comment: sometimes I want to see all records starting with 18  and sometimes the one not starting with 18 and sometimes just all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If SQL Server supported regular expressions, this would be easy.

One thing you could do is to parse the expression.  So, this does what you want:

```
where (accountNumber like @param and @param not like '^%') or
      (accountNumber not like stuff(@param, 1, 1, '') and param like '^%')
```

You could then pass in the parameter as `'18%'` for `like` and `'^18%'` for `not like`.

Or, you could just use two parameters:

```
where accountNumber like @like_param and
      accountNumber not like @notlike_param
```

The default values would be something like `'%'` for `@like_param` and `''` for `@notlike_param`.

Comment: thank you very much for this great solution, I chose the first option with the parsing of the expression